# Close additional cmd window from .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have the a .bat file which starts my web development environment which contains the following:

```
@echo off
...starting applications
start "" "#path_to_glassfish#\asadmin" start-domain
...open some more stuff
```

This starts my local instance of the backend application. This is as far as I know working as intended. The problem occurs when the server is done loading, because it does not close the extra window it created.
Earlier I tried to run it in the script itself but that prevents the instructions after that not to run. Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working as I expect, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the output from [`HELP START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)?

Comment: Not sure if you can fix this. If you close the cmd window manually, does the server part still work? or did that terminate as well?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, the server will keep working after closing the window

Comment: Then the best way to deal with this, is by using taskkill to kill the window. You may need to artificially create a delay before killing it, or given that it actually is another batch script, edit that script to make it stop naturally.

Answer (score 1):

#### When the server is done loading it does not close the extra window it created.

You can use `start` with the `/b` option:

```
start /b "" "#path_to_glassfish#\asadmin" start-domain
```

> `/B` - Start application without creating a new window. In this case ^C will be ignored - leaving ^Break as the only way to interrupt the application.

Source - [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this only moves the problem from one window to another, since after executing the `asadmin` the window returns to awaiting user input, whereas it used to close after finishing all operations

Comment: @DrIvol Then put `exit` at the end of your batch file.

Comment: This also does not work. I assume this is because the original window is exited, but since the output from the second window (which is also in the original) prevents this.

Comment: @DrIvol Is `asadmin` another batch file?

Comment: Yes it is. It accepts arguments like `enable-secure-admin` and `restart-domain` and then performs them as an admin for the application server.

Comment: @DrIvol Then use `call "#path_to_glassfish#\asadmin" start-domain` instead of `start ...` and add `exit` after `...open some more stuff`